# Displaying Main and Subplot Titles in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

As shown in the screenshot we are seeing only one title - for one of the two subplots. I am missing some detail on how to display the following *three* titles:

- Overall plot
- subplot 1
- subplot 2

Here is relevant code for subplots and titles:

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Power Iteration Clustering Inputs And Outputs') #NO show
    ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
    self.plotInputCircles(ax)
    ax.set_title('Input Circles Data',fontsize='medium')  #Shows up!
    ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
    self.plotOutputs(ax)
    ax.set_title('Output Pseudo Eigenvector',fontsize='medium')  #NO show
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1, wspace=0.2)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

**UPDATE** the subroutines are corrupting the title displays (as suspected by @cel) . Per suggesion of @cel I am posting an answer stating as much.

Comment: I do not see this issue here. Which backend are you using? And can you show the magic happening in `plotOutputs` and `plotInputCircles`?

Comment: @cel  You are on the correct track: the subroutines are corrupting the title output. I have updated the OP. I can not show the subroutines here though. I am planning to close the question.

Comment: @cel  I have briefly added the output showing you are correct in the suspicion.  I will try to find out what the real issue and post it as an answer.  Somehow i'd like to give you credit - any suggestion?

Comment: Feel free to answer your question. I didn't spend time to write an answer, so your acknowlegement in the comments is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with titles. Per hint by @cel I looked more closely at the two subroutines that generate the subplots. One of them had a sneaky list comprehension bug.

For readers here is updated info using a dummy sin/cos that works fine instead of the subroutines.

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Power Iteration Clustering Inputs And Outputs')
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
x = np.linspace(-2.5,2.5,100)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
# self.plotInputCircles(ax)
ax.set_title('Labeled Input Circles Data',fontsize='medium')
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
# self.plotOutputs(ax)
x = np.linspace(-2.5,2.5,100)
ax.plot(x, np.cos(x))
ax.set_title('Output Pseudo Eigenvector',fontsize='medium')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=1.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]